# How can I bypass request validation for a single field?

Tags: asp.net

I can see the need for request validation in this age of XSS and other hacks.
But it can be a bit of overkill, it's like cutting off your child's legs to ensure he won't run onto the road and get killed.

We're getting complaints from that it isn't possible to set a password like `<password>`.
The only way to fix this, as far as I can tell, is to set `ValidateRequest="false"` on a whole bunch of pages (such as registration, logon, reset password).  And when using .NET 4.0, you also need to set `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` for the whole application.

Is this really the only way?  Is there no way to state that only the password field should not be validated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asp.net 4 you can create your custom server side request validator which could possibly accept such atypical requests. Writing one is easy, the first googled example should let you start writing your own:

http://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/creating-your-own-custom-request-validation/

Comment: Thanks, that could work.  An example that is even closer to what I need can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.requestvalidator.aspx).
We're currently still using .NET 2.0, but are planning to move to 4.0 on a rainy day, so then this will become a good option.

Comment: By the way, "such atypical requests"?  What is so atypical about not wanting to show an error page just because a user wants a `<` in their password?

Comment: It's because of the way the default validator behaves. Nothing wrong in your requirement. The assumption of the default validator is that anything resembling script is a possible threat. Kind of paranoid.

Comment: This was especially useful advice for me to handle GS1 group separators <GS> safely in web apps.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.Net MVC, you now have [the following options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx) for disabling request validation:

Disable request validation on a controller action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
ActionResult SomeAction(string validationIgnored){...}
```

On a property on a (View)Model:

```
[AllowHtml]
string SomeProperty {get; set;}
```

Or use `Request.Unvalidated()` on posted form fields:

```
var rawField = Request.Unvalidated().Form["field"];
```