# Fail to send html content to webservice gives error not found

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, web-services, wcf

I am trying to send html content as a string to a webservice but failing with an error not found although the same call works if i send a simple string like "test".

**Webservice Code:**

```
public string List(DateTime showdate, string viewtype, int timezone, string test)
{
    ------ whatever ------
}
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
var showdate = "22/05/2014",
    viewtype =  "rest",
    timezone = 2,
    test = $("body").html(); // if i change to something like: test = "My name is Inigo Montoya" it works fine.

$.ajax({
    type: option.method,
    url: option.url,
    data: {"showdate": showdate, "viewtype": viewtype, "timezone": timezone, "test": test},
    success: function(data){ //--- whatever --- },
    error: function(data){ //--- whatever --- }
});
```

Comment: try changing to this `timezone = "2",`

Comment: This is not my problem at all i receive this just fine.

Comment: try this `test = $("body").html();.toString();`

Comment: This error can also occur due to the length of string you are trying to send.

Comment: your answer "test = $("body").html();.toString();" will give a syntax error but set that aside .html() returns a string casting it using .toString() will do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the chrome inspector on your code testing page, and directly paste the above javascript code to see what kind of error is returned.

I can think of 2 problems now:

**Over-lengthy URL**

The jQuery code that you used to fire the ajax call should be fine, but those 2 params `type` and `data` can leads to the problem.

For example, if `$("body").html()` is over 2000 characters and the request method is set as `GET`, the ajax call won't work because the URL will be too long to be understood by the browser.

Given that you mentioned

> if i change to something like: test = "My name is Inigo Montoya" it works fine.

I believe the possiblility of this issue is quite high.

**Cross-domain ajax**

If the target location is a foreign domain, they can potential deny the access by your AJAX call.

Same as above, it is highly recommended to check this problem via Chrome inspector for this issue.

Comment: Chrome inspector is my first resort but this won't solve my problem if it was a length issue how to solve provide a solution please and i'll mark your answer.

Comment: To solve the length issue, you can simply set your request method to "post" and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as you tagged under webservices and json, Hope this should work for you,

```
var data={"showdate": showdate, "viewtype": viewtype, "timezone": timezone, "test": test};
var jsonData= JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
    type: option.method,
    url: option.url,
    data: jsonData,
    success: function(data){ //--- whatever --- },
    error: function(data){ //--- whatever --- }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be hitting ASP's built-in request validation which is used to prevent XSS (Cross-site-scripting).

By default, posting a field which contains HTML can cause it reject a request.

> Request validation is a feature in ASP.NET that examines an HTTP request and determines whether it contains potentially dangerous content. In this context, potentially dangerous content is any HTML markup or JavaScript code in the body, header, query string, or cookies of the request. ASP.NET performs this check because markup or code in the URL query string, cookies, or posted form values might have been added for malicious purposes.

Have a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Note that it is possible to disable request validation for a single field instead of doing it site-wide...

(taken from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19442121/156755))

On a controller action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
ActionResult SomeAction(string validationIgnored){...}
```

or a specific model property:

```
[AllowHtml]
string SomeProperty {get; set;}
```

Note thst this protection is here for a reason, and if you disable it, you're accepting responsibility for validating the input yourself. Have a look at [this blog post by Rick Strahl](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Jul/19/NET-HTML-Sanitation-for-rich-HTML-Input) for some suggestions and alternatives.

Comment: Those attributes will not work in web service i guess they are used in asp.net web methods but not in .svc web service.

Comment: @BeyondProgramming Apologies, I assumed you were using the new [Web Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833994(v=vs.108).aspx). You may wish to add a WCF tag if you're using WCF services. Can you also add some version info so we know what version of the framework you're using? Thanks. Incidentally, there's another way to disable validation through web.config (See MSDN link). No idea if that will apply but worth a try?